# Is there a faster way to get information from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Let's suppose I have seven tables, and I want to perform the same query on all of them, and then return the result. Right now I have some code like this

```
$dates = array();
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $result = runStatement("
    SELECT MIN(StartDate) as Start, 
           MAX(EndDate) as End 
           FROM $table WHERE ProjectID = ?",
    array($id));
  $stageDates[$table] = $result[0];
}
echo json_encode($dates);
```

It works, but it is prohibitively slow because it has to initiate and retrieve results from seven different queries. Is there a way to amalgamate all of the queries into one? Is there any other way to speed it up?

Comment: union, but its probably not faster just 'cleaner'

Comment: union will be faster in the end, since it will be a single request to DB-server, where as current solution makes seven

Comment: my union benchmarking some time back showed little increase, but maybe that was just me

Comment: Do the tables all have the same schema?  If so, is there some reason you don't have the data stored in one table (with a column to identify the differentiator)?  You could then perform a single `SELECT` that groups the results by that differentiating column.

Comment: @Dagon: Or your PC and/or network being very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using join with subquery will solve the problem

```
SELECT
  MIN(t1.StartDate) as Start,
  MAX(t1.EndDate) as End,
  t2.Start,
  t2.END,
  t3.Start,
  t3.END  
FROM table1 as t1
  left join (SELECT
           MIN(t2.StartDate) as Start,
           MAX(t2.EndDate) as End
         FROM table1) as t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
  left join (SELECT
           MIN(t3.StartDate) as Start,
           MAX(t3.EndDate) as End
         FROM table1) as t3
    on t1.id = t3.id  
    -- and so on --  
WHERE t1.ProjectID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Never **ever** put a query inside loop. That's one of the worst things to do.

I don't think you will get a faster way, but, as Dagon said, union will be a lot cleaner and safer way.

```
SELECT MIN(StartDate) as Start, MAX(EndDate) as End FROM $table1, $table2, $table3 WHERE ProjectID = ?",
```

Comment: never say **never** there are always exceptions :-)

Comment: this will fetch a cartisian produc

Answer (score 0):

If you have seven tables with 'StartDate', 'EndDate' and 'ProjectID', you could use materialized views (http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/03/23/using-flexviews-part-one-introduction-to-materialized-views/) or index the data with Solr or Sphinx. The queries then are much faster, with the drawback that your data can outdate. If a few seconds or minute are no problem take a look at those solutions.